# Use map vs array[0] in React component to render the only result filtered by Graphql variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

Based on a Graphql variable `myKey` I query one item of the array of objects:

```
const { data } = useQuery<GqlRes, Args>(GET_ITEMS, {
    variables: {
      myKey,
    },
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  });
```

I have to render a Link in my React jsx:

```
          data.items.map((item) => (
            <Link to={item.url}>
              {item.title}
            </Link>
          ))}
```

Is it better to use `.map` (which in this case returns only one item) or do I have to use something like:

```
const myLink = data.items[0]
```

And then use the values like:

```
<Link to={myLink.url}>
 {myLink.title}
</Link>
```

Comment: You can use destructuring too, like const [myLink] = data.items;
I think it depends if it always returns 1 item, then you dont need map.

Answer (score 0):

If you always expect to get only one item, doing `data.items[0]` is fine but there is not harm in using `map` either. Using `map` will keep your code dynamic and will be able to render multiple links should the returned data contain more than one result.